# designing pivot table in MS SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to develop a pivot table but unable to get required result. Please see the attached image for required output. I am unable to design the pivot query for the required solution.

This is my sql query ::

```
select 
    b.SchoolName,
    c.KaryakramName,
    a.NikashaAmount
from TBL_NIKASHA a
inner join TBL_SCHOOL b on b.SchoolId = a.SchoolId
inner join TBL_KARYAKRAM c on a.KaryakramId = c.KaryakramId
WHERE 
a.NikashaType = 1 and c.karyakramType = 1
order by a.SchoolId;
```

Here, NikashaType & karyakramType come from user.

[image]

I have to show the result of this query in pivot table. What I have done so far::

```
declare
    @columns nvarchar(max) = '',
    @sql nvarchar(max) = '';
    
select
    @columns += QUOTENAME(c.KaryakramName) + ','
from TBL_NIKASHA a
inner join TBL_SCHOOL b on b.SchoolId = a.SchoolId
inner join TBL_KARYAKRAM c on a.KaryakramId = c.KaryakramId
WHERE 
a.NikashaType = 1 and c.karyakramType = 1

SET @columns = left(@columns, len(@columns)-1);

set @sql = '
    select * from 
(
        select c.KaryakramName
        from TBL_NIKASHA a
        inner join TBL_SCHOOL b on b.SchoolId = a.SchoolId
        inner join TBL_KARYAKRAM c on a.KaryakramId = c.KaryakramId
        WHERE 
        a.NikashaType = 1 and c.karyakramType = 1
        order by a.SchoolId
) t
pivot
(
    a.NikashaAmount,
    for c.KaryakramName in ('+ @columns+')
) as pivot_table
';


execute sp_execute @sql;
```

I am  getting error as : Procedure expects parameter '@handle' of type 'int'.

Comment: `sp_executesql` *not* `sp_execute`.

Comment: Separate note, it's ill advised to use `+=` for string aggregation. Use `STRING_AGG` or the older `FOR XML PATH` solution.

Comment: @Larnu getting error `Procedure or function 'sp_execute' expects parameter '@handle', which was not supplied.`

Comment: ... `sp_executesql`... **NOT** `sp_execute`... Stop trying to use `sp_execute`, it's the *wrong* object,